# Angular: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable'

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am using Nativescript here to build a mobile App. There is an error here. In my ASP.Net MVC 5 development using Visual Studio 2017, it is fine using `$http.get().then()`, but in Nativescript it does not.

Please see the code bellow:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./home.component.css"]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.http.get('https://somewebsite.com',
            {
                params: { 'sorter': '', 'isAscending': 'true', 'searchString': '', 'currentPage': '1', 'itemsPerPage': '300' },
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Basic encryptedcodehere"
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                var theData = JSON.parse(response.data);
                if (theData.Data != null && theData.Data.length > 0) {
                    log(theData.Data);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

The error is: `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable'.`?

What is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `subscribe` is probably the way to go. However, if you really want to use `then` (which can be handy if you need to chain calls), you can convert your observable to a promise using the `toPromise()` method

```
this.http.get('https://somewebsite.com',
{
    //... 
}).toPromise().then(response => {
       //...
        });
```

Comment: This approach is good only if you need to get promise for a compatibility with some old or 3rd party code. Otherwise recommended to use .subscribe or .do.

Comment: But if you will use .do to put there your code, you should call .subscribe in any case. It's how works observable. It can return data only for those who are subscribed.

Answer (score 5):

`.then` is the method of Promise. But you use an httpClient, which returns Observable. You should use `.subscribe` instead of `.then`.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('https://somewebsite.com',
        {
            params: { 'sorter': '', 'isAscending': 'true', 'searchString': '', 'currentPage': '1', 'itemsPerPage': '300' },
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic encryptedcodehere"
            }
        }).subscribe(function (data) {
            var theData = JSON.parse(data);
            if (theData.Data != null && theData.Data.length > 0) {
                log(theData.Data);
            }
        });
  }
```

You could read more about [httpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) and [Observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables) in an official documentation

Comment: Eugene answer is correct. You could probably check the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
 selector: "Home",
 moduleId: module.id,
 templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
 styleUrls: ["./home.component.css"]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('https://somewebsite.com',
        {
            params: { 'sorter': '', 'isAscending': 'true', 'searchString': '', 
 'currentPage': '1', 'itemsPerPage': '300' },
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic encryptedcodehere"
            }
        }).subscribe(data => { // no need to write the function you can simply create a arrow function too 
            var theData = JSON.parse(data);
            if (theData.Data != null && theData.Data.length > 0) {
                log(theData.Data);
            }
        });
  }
}
```

it throws the error because then is a method from promise